# Qt Image From Web

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwebview, qwebelement

I'd like PyQt to load an image and display it from the web. Dozens of examples I've found online did not work, as they are for downloading the image.

I simply want to view it.

Something like

```
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/content/img/so/logo.png"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 

web = QtWebKit.QWebView()
web.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Tux.png"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i just get a blank dialog, is there something missing?

Comment: Works fine here - system Python 2.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.5.7, PyQt 4.1.3 -- what versions/platform have you got?

Comment: Kubuntu, Python 2.5.1 - executing from Eric4.

Comment: Darn, I have no kubuntu to check (only plain ubuntu and Mac) -- guess you could easily try executing from command line just to ensure eric4's got nothing to do with it...?  BTW, what PyQt release?